# Eclipse: Space between lines increased

Tags: android, eclipse, android-xml

There is probably a very simple solutions for this, but i accidentally pressed something and now there is more space between the lines than usual, how can i fix it? Its not really a big deal but its annoying that one Xml file looks different than the others.

This is how it looks:

[image]

And this is how it looked before:

[image]

Comment: I went through a few preferences in eclipse and could not get it to reproduce the problem how the hell did this happen, you pressed a key combination on the keyboard or clicked something randomly??

Comment: I pressed some keys by accident and don't know which ones :P

Comment: It was probably a combination of keys

Answer (score 2):

The problem fixed itself! After restarting my computer and eclipse several times the line spacing is now back to normal.

Comment: Must say this is a good fix. In my case I add some Chinese characters which increase the line height. Delete all the characters that use a different font that is bigger than letters, restart Eclipse and the original line height is back.

Answer (score 0):

Is it zoomed in? Ctrl + scroll wheel should solve it/cause it.

*Edit: you could try changing the font size. Instructions here:
http://alagad.com/2007/06/15/changing-the-font-size-in-eclipse/

*Edit 2: Ctrl and plus/minus buttons? I don't have eclipse at work to try these.

Comment: I tried it but then it just scrolls up and down very quickly

Comment: Tried that method but i dont think the problem is in the font size :/

Answer (score 0):

I've cloned and installed the font from

https://github.com/andreberg/Meslo-Font

and made it my IDE editor font for Eclipse. Line spacing is much better now!

Comment: Did you have the same issue with the spacing?